# python pandas add leading zero to make all months 2 digits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add a leading zero so i have a minimum of double digits.

```
     Week product  quantity        Month
0  201301    coke       1.5           1
1  201302   fanta       1.7           2
2  201304    coke       3.6           5
3  201306  sprite       2.4          10
4  201308   pepsi       2.9          12
```

i.e convert the above dataframe to be the below:

```
     Week product  quantity         Month
0  201301    coke       1.5           01
1  201302   fanta       1.7           02
2  201304    coke       3.6           05
3  201306  sprite       2.4           10
4  201308   pepsi       2.9           12
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

use `map()` method of Series with `"{:02}".format`:

```
data = """     Week product  quantity        Month
0  201301    coke       1.5           1
1  201302   fanta       1.7           2
2  201304    coke       3.6           5
3  201306  sprite       2.4          10
4  201308   pepsi       2.9          12
"""

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df["Month"] = df.Month.map("{:02}".format)
```

Comment: Can explain the reasoning to the syntax `.map("{:02}".format)` ? This is very helpful btw.

Comment: Please use map("{:02d}".format) instead of map("{:02}".format) in case you get error

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.7 you can format this value using

```
>>> month = 9
>>> '{:02}'.format(month)
'09'
```

here 2 in {:02} specifies convert the input digit in 2 chars by prefixing '0'. If input digit is of length 2 then that digit will remain unchanged.

Comment: Looking at your previous question I suggest - df['MonthMax'] = '{:02}'.format(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['LastDayWeek']).month)

Comment: sorry I was not clear my question was in relation to a pandas dataframe and i needed all the values in a column updated . HYRY explanation below with the .map did the trick in this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

In Python versions earlier than 2.7, there is printf-style formatting:

```
>>> month = 9
>>> '%02d' % month
'09'
```

See the [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more information.